# Localizing my website ruins formatting

Tags: html, css, reactjs, web-applications, redux

I am creating a website with form fields, tables with headers, etc...

My problem is that I am afraid that when I change the language, some of the formatting will be messed up. Such things like 1 lines becoming 2 and headers being cut off by the small width of a column will make the page look weird.

What are some options and paths to go down. Do they scale well for an application with almost 100 pages?

Answer (score 0):

Well - you always should create websites with flexibility in mind. To solve the problem, you must ensure you aren't using fixed sizes (width, height and others).

No need to localize, just add more english words and see how the layout reacts. Resize the screen to mobile and you can also check the behavior.

To easily allow flexible content, I almost always end up using CSS [flexbox](http://apps.workflower.fi/css-cheats/?name=flexbox) and [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to create layouts based on relative units.